# Cannot convert a json file to parquet using spark

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am using spark 1.6.0. I have a json file. It is given below.

```
{"id" : "1201", "name" : "shamir", "age" : "25"}
```

I am trying to convert it to parquet. Below is my code.

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
import sqlContext.sql
val employee = sqlContext.read.json("emp.json")
employee.write.parquet("employee.parquet")
```

I am getting a huge error. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error that I am getting.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have to paste the error you are getting. Also let me know the spark version you are using.

Comment: @DurgaViswanathGadiraju I have pasted the error I was getting.

Comment: I am using spark 1.6.0

Comment: Copy the full error text (stack trace and error message) and paste it into your question. Don't just show a snapshot because it doesn't show all information.

Comment: @Zoltán, I can't go any higher

Comment: Please cut and paste the TEXT of your error. Not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the error message, little can be done to answer but the following two lines should work (tested on Spark 1.5.2):

```
val employee = sqlContext.jsonFile("emp.json")
employee.saveAsParquetFile("employee.parquet")
//Equivalent to :
employee.write.format("parquet").mode(SaveMode.ErrorIfExists).save("employee.parquet")
```

If not, it may be a problem of your system configuration or your output path accessibility.

Note that `employee.write.parquet("employee.parquet")` is equivalent to `employee.write.format("parquet").save("employee.parquet")`

Comment: I am using windows. The error is too large. I cannot see it entirely in the command promt. I have tried your code. I am getting the same error.

Comment: @eddard.stark You should identify whether the error is raised by the reading of the json file or the writing into a parquet file. If the former is the case: Have you checked that `emp.json` is in the same directory than the current directory is in the terminal you are launching `spark-shell`?

Comment: I am using spark 1.6.0

Comment: @eddard.stark Its a configuration problem for sure. Have you checked whether you have write access at you current directory?

Comment: @eddard.stark Before launching your spark-shell go to your spark configuration directory; copy `log4j.properties.example` file to `log4j.properties` and edit it. Changing the appender `log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender` and `log4j.appender.FILE.File=SOME_PATH/log.out` So you can get the entire log in a file (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_files.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try to coalesce to fewer partitions before you save

```
employee.coalesce(numPartitions).write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet("employee.parquet")
```